# Webpack devserver proxy not working to get round CORS issue

Tags: javascript, c#, webpack, cors, webpack-dev-server

I have a React app which is running webpackdevserver on port 3000.

I have an AWS .NetCore Lambda server running localhost on port 5050.

When I try and make a request I am getting the cors error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5050/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I was hoping to use a proxy, as per the documtation here in order to forward my requests on using the same domain to get round this.

https://medium.com/@drgenejones/proxying-an-external-api-with-webpack-serve-code-and-a-restful-data-from-separate-endpoints-4da9b8daf430

However it is not working, I don't see any difference at all with the settings applied, can anyone help?

```
devServer: {
  port: 3000,
  disableHostCheck: true,
  compress: true,
  host: 'localhost',
  proxy: {
    '/': {
      target: 'http://localhost:5050',
      secure: false,
    },
  },
},
```

My JavaScript to call the server is like this...  I have also tried with the url `http://localhost:3000` but this just returns a bad request error.

```
  const result = await fetch('http://localhost:5050', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }),
    body: JSON.stringify({
      method: 'upload',
      test: 'test',
    }),
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is to set `/` which could just fetch the current server so you might need to differentiate between your web app vs your server (most likely via a specific path such as `/api`, but you can choose to pass this path to your proxy server or not).

So you would change as following:

- Your configuration of proxy first to take `api` to go through proxy:

```json
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:5050',
    pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}, // In this case we don't pass `api` path
  }
}
```

- Next thing is to change your code to call the same domain + port `3000` normally (proxy would do the rest for you by passing to your server with port `5050` which you configured):

```js
const result = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I guess my issue is that I am using an AWS lambda, so I don't really know if I can make a different endpoint for it, they all seem to just be on the root, where I pass in a different body.

Comment: The `api` path is all about to get to know which endpoint should be passed to proxy so it won’t affect to your server at all since it would send to your root server url

Comment: Ahh ok, sorry I see what you mean.  I've tried that but now I am getting the following error `POST http://localhost:3000/api net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (Bad Request)`  any ideas?

Comment: You can check the log in your terminal and debug your local server to get to know more about error. Also check if proxy are passing request to the server accordingly as well

Comment: I think i've realised the issue, it doesn't seem I can connect to the endpoint using a normal restAPI, it is using the 'AWS .NET Core 3.1 Mock Lambda Test Tool' which I think must use websockets or something else to connect as I tried in POSTMAN too and I couldn't post anything either.  I've accepted the answer as I think i'm fighting a losing battle.